# Android - Allow access to tablet data security dialog

Tags: android, tablet, samsung-galaxy, soti, mobicontrol

I have been given the task to get some android tablets (SM-T500) working in kiosk mode (soti mobicontrol).
The issue is when they are in kiosk mode it blocks the USB switcher menu and the allow access to tablet data popup

I have managed to get the USB switcher menu working by allowing **com.android.settings/.Settings$UsbDetailsActivity** to launch but for the life of me I cannot workout what apk strand that controls the "Allow access to tablet data" security dialog box

I am new to android and usually only work with ios.... would anybody be able to point me in the right direction??

Comment: How did you get com.android.settings/.Settings$UsbDetailsActivity to launch?

Comment: Hey @K-man since last year Android have changed the setting that opens the USB switcher it is now **com.samsung.android.mtp/.MtpPopupActivity**  

In Mobicontrol - profiles > create or edit a profile > configuration > lockdown > add home screen items > **Launch:// com.samsung.android.mtp/.MtpPopupActivity**  

We have customised the home screen, so the end user doesn't see this program.    
When the user plugs in the tablet to the computer they get the prompt on the tablet to trust the computer.  

Hope this helps, reach out if you need screenshots or further explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Working with Soti we have found the activity that runs this popup message is com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.USBConnection - allowing this to the whitelist allowed it through the kiosk mode (just in case anyone falls into the same black hole i did)